# How to execute an external program using lib_mysqludf_sys when an UPDATE happens?

Tags: c++, mysql

I have used `lib_mysqludf_sys` to execute the following C++ programs executable file in MySQL, I executed:

```
mysql> SELECT sys_exec('/home/eden/Desktop/ins_data');
```

It returned:

```
sys_exec('/home/eden/Desktop/ins_data')
32512
```

Actually in my `ins_data` executable file I inserted a new row in to MySQL database, but after executing this it is not inserting any new row.

I'm not understanding what output it is returning, I'm using C++ connector program to insert a new row.

Comment: Could that be an error code? Probably. If you have access to the source code of `ins_data` you will probably have to add some more exception check in order to trace the issue back to its source.

Answer (score 0):

[AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) limits execution of your UDF function.

 This will stop apparmor 

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor stop`

 and this will disable mysql profile 

`sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/`

`sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`